# Converting long strings to short hash before sql comparison queries - improves performance?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, hash

A website is exposing a list of URL addresses, the second website is regularly checking out this list and its goal is to tell if any new addresses appeared there. The list is "moving" which means that new addresses appears gradually but old disappears.

Second website stores addresses in database for comparison. The question is - how would be faster to do this, speed is a key.

1. Gets a list from first website, delete from database old addresses that are not on our list, insert to database addresses that are on the list, but were not in the database.

OR

2. As above, but do this with CRC32 strings got from those addresses.

I'm thinking like this - those URL addresses can be arbitrarily long, converting them to CRC32 before database searches seems to guarantee linear increase of database load, when searching for/deleting them from the database.

On the other hand, converting them to CRC32 strings on PHP level puts more load on http server, and the question is - is converting them beforehand faster than using whole in WHERE clause of sql query?

BTW. Yes, CRC32 have enough of uniqueness for my use case.

Comment: How many of:1)  urls? 2) old urls expiring and how often do you need to check that they have expired? 3) New urls and how often? Using something like `Redis` as a `cache` and 'database' could be useful. We need to now the totals values and 'rates of change'.

Comment: URLs won't be that many (something like 50-100), but the websites exposing them may be hundreds. So the above problem will be multiplicated by the possible vast number of websites exposing those urls, and we will need to be up to date, so the code will be running maybe every 30 minutes or maybe even more frequently. The point is that the table with those urls will be possibly very big with very frequent reads and writes.

Answer (score 1):

In your description it seems that you always replace the database with the new list so it would be better to use the original strings. 
Anyway if the table is indexed, the performance improvement would be smaller than the overhead to convert the string to int in almost every modern db.

Answer (score 1):

if indexing is not an option i would recommend looking at [xxhash](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash)
but i have to say i really don't know if there is a fast implementation for php.

Comment: xxhash sounds fast, but I suspect that the speed of any of the digests is insignificant compared to the time taken for inserting/selecting the row.

Comment: My recommendation is only meant for environments where it could be an problem. I wouldn't underestimate the time it takes to hash stuff if you don't have optimized and hardware accelerated algorithm support. ;)